# Update PATH without altering the env variables already there

Tags: batch-file, path

My PATH has few entries like `%SystemRoot%`, `%USERPROFILE%/`... etc which are pointing to another env variable. But when I update the PATH with command line, it replaces those env entries with actual value like e.g. below

Earlier Entry : `%SystemRoot%;%USERPROFILE%\AppData`

```
SETX MY_ENV "C:\MyData"
SETX PATH %MY_ENV%;%PATH%
```

Path Value : `C:\MyData;C:\Windows;C:\USers\UserName\AppData`

But, I am looking for a solution which can be run directly as cmd line por through Batch programming that will set my Path as below

```
%MY_ENV%;%%SystemRoot%;%USERPROFILE%\AppData
```

This is not the Path variable meant for logged in user but is the system path variable.

Comment: Do not use `setx` for modifying the `PATH` variable! The value of `%PATH%` you see is a mixture of a user-defined and a system-level `PATH` variable definition in the Registry; `setx` messes around with them!

Comment: It's not messing the content there but it expands the env variables used in Path to the actual location. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Well, `%PATH%` returns a combination of user- and system-level PATH settings, so `setx PATH %MY_ENV%;%PATH%` writes the result to the user-defined PATH setting in the registry, that is what I meant by "messing around". I guess it is smarter to modify the registry settings directly...